# Voice output on navigation

Tags: voice, indoor-positioning-system

Any ideas on how to incorporate a voice output into the map to give a turn by turn direction on a smartphone. We are using Mapkit and Cloudmade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this has very little to share with indoor or outdoor positioning and navigation. It is mainly a matter of converting the text output of a pathfinding/routing application/server to voice using a text-to-speech (TTS) system.

For example, you could use the [Open Source Routing Machine (OSRM)](http://project-osrm.org/) or [OpenTripPlanner](http://opentripplanner.com/) to generate a list of turn-by-turn indications and the text to speech library of Android > 2.2 to convert them into voice. Have a look to the TTS Android documentation:

[An introduction to Text-To-Speech in Android](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2009/09/introduction-to-text-to-speech-in.html)

[TextToSpeech](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html)

Of course, MapKit and/or CloudMade may have their own routing system (I do not use them and I do not know it). In this case, you just have to read their documentation.